# Another way to perform multithreading than using static method and variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a program that starts 1000 threads, each thread adds 1 to a variable sum. here's the code:

```
public class Test1 implements Runnable{
    public Test1( ) {

    }
    public void run() {
        Sum.sum++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Sum s = new Sum();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Test1());
            try {
                t.start();
                t.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
        System.out.println(Sum.getSum());
    }
}


public class Sum {
    static int sum;

    public Sum() {
        sum = 0;
    }

    public static int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public static void setSum(int sum) {
        sum = sum;
    }


}
```

Is there a way that creates an instance of the Sum class, then each thread adds 1 to the same instance of the Sum class? I mean not using a static method or variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test1 implements Runnable{
Sum s = null;
public Test1(Sum s) {
this.s = s;
}
public void run() {
    s.sum++;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sum s = new Sum();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Test1(s));
            t.start();
    }   
    System.out.println(s.getSum());
}
}


class Sum {
int sum;

public Sum() {
    sum = 0;
}

public int getSum() {
    return sum;
}

public void setSum(int sum) {
    sum = sum;
}
```

}

***Important notes :***

1 - sleep() is static, so it acts on the current running thread, so if you meant to sleep thread t, the correct way to do it is as in the answer

2- System.out.println(s.getSum()); isn't guaranteed to run after all threads finish .... If you want to do so, use ExecutorService

3- do your synchronized add() method instead of accessing the variable directly .... here it wont matter much, but in real life example, you might encounter race condition

Comment: Actually i did the same before, but isn't it gonna make a new instance of Sum each thread? or maybe i got it wrong?

Comment: no because all are working on the same object 's' ........ if you said

    public void run() {
    Sum s = new Sum();    
    s.sum++;
    }
It will make a new instance in each thread

Comment: This answer is bad. Without the synchronization you mention, the behavior is unpredictable.

Comment: I just made the minimal change to fulfill the need, but sure .... synchronization should be used as I mentioned ... but since the logic "here" is so simple, no concurrent reads and writes, even no processing but a simple increment of a single variable .... I can't imagine a logic of unpredictable result

Comment: 1) You've declared `s` as a local variable. It's out of scope in `run`. 2) If you meant it to be an instance field, then you're not answering the question which asked for a single `Sum` shared by all threads. 3) If you do make a single `Sum` shared by all threads, then without synchronization everything fails.

Comment: This is a school assignment, which compares the answer between a none synchronization and a well synchronization. But each time the new operator called, the system will allocates new memory to store it. Is it a way to let the system use the same instance/memory location? thus every thread uses the reference of that instance

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis , yes you are correct for the first 2 points, I really didn't recognize some code lines, but concerning the third point, why will everything fail ??? yes the result of System.out.println(s.getSum()); isn't predictable but it seems that this is what Wesley wants to test

Comment: `s.sum++;` is not an atomic operation.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis  So it isn't possible to create a single instance of `Sum` which shared by all 1000 threads without synchronization?

Comment: @Wesley.C You can share it just fine. It won't be usable without proper concurrency controls like synchronization.